# Xamarin Build failed. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:1

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am getting this error while building a project on xamarin studio. Few hours back it was working properly, then I connected an external device to run my project on that device. after connecting that device I am getting this error message. Please Help. Thanks

Build failed. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:1875 Build: 1 error, 0 warnings

Comment: Have you ran any other applications on that device before?

Comment: No never. After disconnecting that device it is still faild to build the solution

Comment: which platform you are trying?? android, ios??? not mentioned

Comment: Yes I did. I think It is not because of that device. It is not even building the project.

Comment: I am trying on Android platform using c#

Comment: can you please post complete stack strace of exception.

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=D7D91460627F7EE5&id=D7D91460627F7EE5%21147

Comment: Sorry @Bedant, but this link is blocked in my network.